# UDP traffic with Scapy

Tags: udp, scapy

I want to generate UDP traffic to  a specific address using defined source port number but no destination port number. 
I tried the following script -

```
msg='hello'
p=IP(dst="192.168.10.55")/UDP(sport=5001)/Raw(load=msg)
send(p)
```

But the generated traffic is sent using DNS port (53). 
Is there a solution to deny the use off the DNS port (I don't want to force destination port).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a destination port. It is required by the protocol. Source port is optional - 0 will be placed in by default otherwise.

See [RFC 768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) for the original standard of the UDP protocol.